# Reverse multi word string

Tags: c++

I want to reverse a string. When I use simple cin then strings are reversed successfully. However for multi word string I need to cin.getline. But the problem is upon using cin.getline the first letter is not displayed in the reversed string. Can someone please point me out the mistake. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Rev_string{

     char source[100], dest[100];
     int pos_source, pos_dest;

     public:
         void func(){

             pos_source=pos_dest=0;
             cout<<"Enter the string to be reversed: ";
             cin.getline(source,sizeof(source));
             //cin>>source;
             cout<<endl;


             while(source[pos_source]!='\0')
             pos_source++;


             --pos_source;

             while(pos_source!=0)
             dest[pos_dest++]=source[pos_source--];


             dest[pos_dest]='\0';


             cout<<"The reversed string is: "<<dest<<endl;
        }


  };

  int main(int argc, char** argv) {

   Rev_string ob;
   ob.func();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char[100]` ? No wonder you have issues. Try `std::string`. That said, `std::reverse` would also be a lot easier. In general you're doing too much yourself. A functions should be fairly simple, and too complex functions should be broken in multiple functions.

Comment: Just a comment, not an answer: if you used `strlen` and a reverse loop, your code would take 3 lines of code. Moreover, you wouldn't need `pos_dest` and `dest` variables. If you used `string`, then your life would be even much easier :)

Comment: What did you observe, when stepping through your code with the debugger?

Comment: I am a student. I know that by using strlen and strrev code will be shorter. This has been given as an assignment where it is mentioned that I can't use any in built functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pos_source` is the index of the last character in the array started with 0. To iterate through the all chars in the array you need also to track the 0-index char, which is skipped now: after processing the element with index 1, `source[pos_source--];` pos_source will be 0 and we will go out from the while loop. That's why you are loosing the first character (which is 0-index).

You can fix it like `while(pos_source >= 0)`.

This is a typical ["off-by-one"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) error.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed the issue. I can't up vote your comment as I don't have enough reputation. I don't know why people without giving the answers always compete to down vote the question. Thank a lot Alexey.

Comment: You should be possible to chose the answer as accepted,

http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work